# Checking if username exists not working?

Tags: php, mysqli

I've checked other answers and try to replicate it into mine, but I'm getting an unidentified `row` error.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

include_once 'dbconnect.php';

//set validation error flag as false
$error = false;

//check if form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
    $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['last_name']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $cpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cpassword']);
    $quote = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['quote']);
    $who = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['who']);

    //name can contain only alpha characters and space
    if ($_POST['username'] == $row['username']){
        $error = true;
        $username_error = '<div class="error-notice">
                            <div class="oaerror danger">
                            <strong>Uh oh!</strong> - Username is already in use.
                            </div>';

    }
```

Comment: Where do you assign the $row?

Comment: oh I didn't... What should I assign it to?

Comment: You should use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Not even `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is 100% safe for injection attacks.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do all of that yet. I'm fairly new so my plan is to progress step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I got it. I had to do this above my code.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username. "'");
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```